# Update view count when opening article in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a collection with some articles.

I want to register the view count and when the article was last opened/read/clicked.

I am using Flow Router to route in my application. But should I update the fields `viewCount` and `lastVisitedAt` in my `action` in `router.js` or in my helpers?

I don't think such 'logic' belongs in the router, but neither does it make sense to put in helpers or events.

Should it probably be done in

```
Template.articleDetail.onCreated(function() {
    var articleId = ...;
    // update viewCount and lastVisitedAt
});
```

Comment: Definitely not in helpers, they can run multiple times and throw off your counts. In the router or onCreated/onRendered handlers

Comment: What's the difference between onCreated and onRendered. To me it seems that onRendered suits better in this context; however, I don't know the exact difference.

Comment: If a template is used multiple times in a route it will be created once, rendered N times.

Comment: Personally I'd put this in the router, quick and unambiguous.

Comment: you could make it part of your middleware?